# cordova create text file on sdcard using intel xdk

Tags: cordova

**My Question:** How to create simple text file using cordova and this text file store sdcard.

My Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.getElementById("createFile").addEventListener("click", createFile);
}

function createFile() {
   var type = window.TEMPORARY;
   var size = 5*1024*1024;

   window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback, errorCallback)

   function successCallback(fs) {
      console.log(fs.root);
      fs.root.getFile('logs.txt', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {
         alert('File creation successfull!')
      }, errorCallback);
   }

   function errorCallback(error) {
      alert("ERROR: " + error.code)
   }

}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<button id = "createFile">CREATE FILE</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Question:**

I click `createFile` button and alert box is being displayed for file creation successfully, but I check my android phone and `logs.txt` file does not find my phone. So please help me how to store text file on sdcard.

Comment: Where in your code does it say to put it in the SD card?

Comment: @Steve i don't know how  to put  sd card code on abobe example

Comment: I don't know how either. Google this: cordova read sd card